# how to find specific row and column with smallest value 2D array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

so i dont have to find the min value but the specific row and column where the min value is located. This is how much i have that is working haha.

```
Scanner dati=new Scanner(System.in); 
int[][] a;
int n,m,i,j,z,vertiba,x,v;
vertiba=0;

do{ 
     System.out.print("How many crows (max=20): ");
     n=dati.nextInt();
}while (n<1 || n>20);

do{
     System.out.print("How many columns (max=20): ");
     m=dati.nextInt();;
}while (m<1 || m>20);
     
System.out.print("enter values ");
a=new int[n][m];
      
for( i=0;i< n ; i++){
    for( j=0; j< m; j++) {
        System.out.print("enter values["+i+"]["+j+"] ");
        v= dati.nextInt();
        a[i][j] = v; 
    }
}

for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for ( j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: when you get each values, check if the input is the minimum. If it is, save `i`and `j`.

Comment: The most straightforward way to find the minimum of any collection of elements is to examine each one and keep track of the least seen so far.  When you have finished examining all the elements, the least so far is the overall least.  If you want to know the location of the least element, then simply record (also) the location each time you update the least so far.  Then at all times, including after processing all the elements, you know the location where the least one seen up to that point was observed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add something like this to the begining

```
int min, minCol, minRow;
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Then you extend your input for loop with an if statement

```
for( i=0;i< n ; i++){
    for( j=0; j< m; j++) {
        System.out.print("enter values["+i+"]["+j+"] ");
        v= dati.nextInt();
        a[i][j] = v; 
        if( v < min ) {
            min = v;
            minRow = i;
            minCol = j;
        }
    }
}
```